# How to enable JWT Authentication for Grafana v8.5.22

Tags: grafana, authentication, json

I've setup Grafana v8.5.22 on Linux Operating System (RHEL) and tried to enable JWT authentication for accessing dashboards with time limit tokens following below process.

1. Generated Public and Private keys at /etc/grafana directory with below commands

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.key

openssl rsa -pubout -in private.key -out public.key

2. Given required access to these 2 files with below commands following same ownership (root:grafana) as like other files in same directory /etc/grafana

chown root:grafana *.key

chmod 777 *.key

(Note: 777 only for temporary, I will change it later after fixing this issue)

3. configured below details in /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

[auth.jwt]

enabled = true

header_name = X-JWT-Assertion

email_claim = sub

username_claim = sub

key_file = /etc/grafana/private.key

auto_sign_up = true

url_login = true

skip_org_role_sync = true

4. restarted grafana with below command

sudo service grafana-server restart

5. generated JWT token with below python3 script

a) Install pyjwt module

pip install pyjwt

b) Python script to generate token as below 'script.py'

import jwt

private_key = open('private.key').read()

token = jwt.encode({'exp': 1681880400, 'sub': 'existinguser@email.com'}, private_key, algorithm='RS256')

print(token)

(Note: exp value here is just for reference. I'm updating it whenever generating new token)

6. Then used the jwt token with below URL for accessing existing dashboard (validated using incognito window)

http://localhost:3000/d/TPQDREZ/simple-streaming-example?orgId=1&kiosk&jwt=<JWT_Token>

7. But it is redirecting me to login page with error status code 302 in logs at /var/log/grafana/grafana.log
   (Note: I have already enabled debug level and then collected logs)

logger=context traceID=000000000000000000000000000 userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2023-04-22T18:14:00.66-0500 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/d/TPQDREZ/simple-streaming-example status=302 remote_addr=127.0.0.1 time_ms=0 duration=164.93µs size=29 referer= traceID=000000000000000000000000000

(Note: I even validated with curl command and observed that it is redirecting me to login page)

I'm getting error status code 302 and getting redirected to login page whenever I use JWT token. Can you please help me understand where is the issue and how to fix it for enabling JWT authentication.